# Is there a way to combine these variables in a way that makes sense?

Tags: gis, stata

Hello stack overflow community!

I am a sociology student working on a thesis project comparing home value appreciation and neighborhood racial composition over time.

I'm currently using two separate data sources and trying to combine them in a way that makes sense without aggregating anything.

The first data source is GIS data which has information on home sales in each year by home. The second is census data which has yearly estimates of racial composition by census tract. Both are in .csv formats.

My goal is to create a set of variables for each home row in the GIS data which represents the racial composition for the tract the home is in at the year it was sold (e.g. home 1 | 2010| $500,000 | Census tract 10 | 10% white).

I began doing this by going into Stata and using the following strategy:

For example, if I'm looking at a home sold in 2010 in Census tract 10 and I find that this tract was 10% white in 2010, using something like

```
   If censustract=10 and year=2010, replace percentwhite = 10
```

However, this seemed incredibly time consuming, as I'm using data that go back decades and a couple dozen Census tracts.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might do this smarter, not harder? The first thought I had was to aggregate the data by census tract and year, but was hoping to avoid that if possible. Thank you so much in advance for your help and have a terrific day and start to the new year!

Comment: This is more a question about research strategy for a project. There is not a concrete, specific programming question here. The code is pseudo-code and wouldn't be legal in Stata. Perhaps better to ask on Cross-Validated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can simply merge census data onto your GIS data. That will be much less painful than using -replace-. Here's an example:

```
*GIS data: information on home sales in each year by home 
clear
input censustract   house_id    year        house_value_k
        10          100         2010            200
        11          101         2020            500
        11          102         1980            100
end
tempfile GIS_data
sa      `GIS_data'

*census data: yearly estimates of racial composition by census tract
clear
input censustract       year        percentwhite 
        10              2010            20
        10              2000            10
        11              2010            25
        11              2000             5
end
tempfile census_data
sa      `census_data'
  
*easy method: merge the census data onto your GIS data      
use `GIS_data', clear
mer m:1 censustract     year        using `census_data'
drop if _merge==2
list 


*hard method: use -replace- 
use `GIS_data', clear
gen     percentwhite=.
replace percentwhite=20 if censustract==10 & year==2010
replace percentwhite=10 if censustract==10 & year==2000
replace percentwhite=25 if censustract==11 & year==2010
replace percentwhite=5  if censustract==11 & year==2000
list
```

Both methods "work", but using -merge- is much easier and less prone to errors.

Note: I intentionally created the data sets so that the merge wouldn't be perfect. You will likely want to drop some of the observations in that case. In the code above I dropped when _merge==2